# Does TeamCity support build steps that execute other TeamCity builds?

Tags: teamcity

Using TeamCity, I've set up several builds in a project. Most of the time I want to run each build as a standalone. However, sometimes I want to execute several builds with the same set of parameters. The builds all use the same template, so all of their parameters could, theoretically, be supplied by a single build.

I can't find anything in the documentation that says this is possible, but it seems like it should be. (searching for "execute builds from another build in teamcity" gives me plenty of documentation on build dependencies, but not what I'm looking for)

I know I can manually queue up all of my builds, but that would require re-entering the same parameters each time.

**Does TeamCity support build steps that execute other TeamCity builds?** If so, **How?**

Comment: You could add a command line step that triggers a build potentially. This may point you in the right direction:  https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP

Comment: Yup. I'd post to the REST API and you can trigger a build. The documentation has a curl example, but I have some PowerShell if it helps. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly. However, in TeamCity you can have a build chain (builds the invoke other dependant builds) by adding a snapshot dependency.

If you add a snapshot dependency on another build configuration, then you can access all its defined parameters and even source and artefacts.

Comment: I hope he got to his laptop

Answer (score 6):

I achieve this by calling the TeamCity REST API:

1. Add a new step at the end of your build, using Command Line runner
2. Do curl

   curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer %TeamCityToken%" 
   --header "Content-Type:application/xml" 
   -d"

   <buildType id="Remote Deploy"/>

   <property name="tag" value="%NewVersion%"/>


   " 
   http://teamcity.example.com/app/rest/buildQueue

You will need to change:

TeamCityToken to your access token, refer to this page to create one: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/teamcity-rest-api-documentation.html#REST+Authentication

Build type id "Remote Deploy" to your build type id.

The properties to whatever you need.

And, of cause, the teamcity url.